# arrangement of six boys and six girls around a table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

If six boys and six girls are to be seated around a circular table alternately, then how is the arrangement equal to $6!5!$ and not $5!5!$ ? I am not able to arrive at a conclusion. Please help.

If $6$ boys sit around a circular table, leaving a place between every two boys vacant then they can be arranged in $5!$ ways. There are now $6$ seats left for $6$ girls such that they too can be arranged in $5!$ ways. Where am I missing out?

Comment: Why do you think it is $5!5!$? What is your reasoning?

Comment: If $6$ boys sit around a circular table , leaving a place between every two boys vacant then they can be arranged in $5!$ ways. There are now $6$ seats left for $6$ girls such that they too can be arranged in $5!$ ways. Where am I missing out ?

Comment: @AditiParetkar If you rotate the ordering of the girls, their position in relation to the boys changes, but you could omit the rotations with boys, because when they are seated, their position has nothing to be related to. Hope you understand me, my English is not perfect

Comment: @AditiParetkar Thanks, your explanation helped me to see where your reasoning mistake is. I updated my Answer

Answer (score 2):

As you understood, with a circular table there is no 'first', 'second', ..., or 'last' chair, and so you have to take one of the persons as an 'anchor' point so that you can differentiate between what seem like different arrangements, but are in fact the same arrangements by rotations.

OK, so you used one of the boys as an anchor point, leaving $5!$ ways to seat the rest of the boys.  But now that the table is 'anchored', you don't 'anchor' it again with a girl. It's *already* anchored with the one boy, so now you just place those 6 girls relative to the boys, and there are $6!$ possible ways to distribute the $6$ girls between the boys.

Comment: Yes I’m sorry I missed out alternating. I’ve edited it. Could you please explain how is it $5!6!$?

Comment: @AditiParetkar  Well, it is *not* $5!6!$, but at least that *part* of the formula is because of the possible rotation.

Comment: @Bram28  If the boys and girls alternate, the answer is $5!6!$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ah!  I missed that in the prompt. Thanks!

Comment: @Bram28 Oh ! I get it now ! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AditiParetkar You're welcome! :)